# Need quick guidance on Xcode project - Deck of Cards

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a fairly noobish Xcode/Cocos2d programmer and I'm trying to wrap my head around a project I've just started.

My goal is to make a 4 player card game in Xcode.  The players draw from a single deck of cards.  Along the way, winning players will gather "sets" of cards which gain them points.

With this in mind, I'm envisioning the need for 9 arrays: Deck of Cards, Player 1 Hand,..., Player 4 Hand, Player 1 Sets,...,Player 4 Hand.  *(I skipped the player 2 and 3 info with "...")*

As the game proceeds, cards will be moved from the deck to players to various players' sets.  For this to happen, cards will be removed from old arrays and added to the new array.

Do I appear to be thinking through this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is very general and there are many ways to look at this.

Your card elements could have a property that specifies which player owns them (one of the owner being the deck and another the discard pile conceivably).

Or, closer to what you have in mind, you could have a map where the keys are your players (and the deck and discard pile) and the map values the arrays containing your cards.